# Run SQL Trigger On Table Update to Set Values on a Different Table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want my SQL server to update a different table from the current table and use that current tables updated information. For example, if I create a trigger on my `warehouse` table so that whenever there's an update executed on `warehouse` the trigger goes and updates the `price_qty_table` using data from multiple other tables. I imagine I need something along the lines of

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_price_qty` AFTER UPDATE
ON `warehouse`
UPDATE `price_qty_table`
SET `price_qty_table`.`price`=`main_table`.`price`, `price_qty_table`.`qty`=`warehouse`.`ca`
WHERE `price_qty_table`.`sku`=`warehouse`.`sku`
```

But this does not work and I get an error of `Unknown column 'price_qty_table'.'price' in 'field list'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that `price_qty_table'.price` exists in your table. And also, you shouldn't use tag `mysql` and `sql-server-triggers` in one post. Pick one, sql server or mysql.

Comment: All the columns exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that doing an inner join on the table that I wanted to cross reference solved this issue.